# reading a text file using different criteria

Tags: python, file-io

I want to read an arff file and separate the attribute and data into different list. The file is [here](https://github.com/lpfgarcia/ucipp/blob/master/uci/balloons-adult-stretch.arff). I tried the following code

```
from itertools import dropwhile
attributes = []
with open('balloons.arff', 'r') as f:
    for l in f.readlines():                                     ##1
        items = l.split(' ')                                    ##2
        if items[0] == '@attribute':                            ##3
            attributes.append(items[1])                         ##4
    data = dropwhile(lambda _line: "@data" not in _line, f)     ##5
    next(data,"")                                               ##6
    for line in data:                                           ##7
            print(line.strip())                                 ##8
    print(attributes)                                           ##9
```

When I run this code, I am getting only the list of attributes but when I comment line numbers ##1 to ##4 (first for loop), the program gives the data part correctly. I have very large files, an efficient solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel. Someone else has already written an ARFF parser for Python, [liac-arff](https://github.com/renatopp/liac-arff). Install it with `pip`:

```
pip install liac-arff
```

Then import and use the module:

```
import arff

with open('balloons-adult-stretch.arff', 'rb') as handle:
    data = arff.load(handle)

print(data['attributes'])
print(data['data'])
```

Output:

```
[(u'V1', [u'PURPLE', u'YELLOW']), (u'V2', [u'LARGE', u'SMALL']), (u'V3', [u'DIP', u'STRETCH']), (u'V4', [u'ADULT', u'CHILD']), (u'Class', [u'1', u'2'])]
[[u'YELLOW', u'SMALL', u'STRETCH', u'ADULT', u'2'], [u'YELLOW', u'SMALL', u'STRETCH', u'CHILD', u'2'], [u'YELLOW', u'SMALL', u'DIP', u'ADULT', u'2'], [u'YELLOW', u'SMALL', u'DIP', u'CHILD', u'1'], [u'YELLOW', u'SMALL', u'DIP', u'CHILD', u'1'], [u'YELLOW', u'LARGE', u'STRETCH', u'ADULT', u'2'], [u'YELLOW', u'LARGE', u'STRETCH', u'CHILD', u'2'], [u'YELLOW', u'LARGE', u'DIP', u'ADULT', u'2'], [u'YELLOW', u'LARGE', u'DIP', u'CHILD', u'1'], [u'YELLOW', u'LARGE', u'DIP', u'CHILD', u'1'], [u'PURPLE', u'SMALL', u'STRETCH', u'ADULT', u'2'], [u'PURPLE', u'SMALL', u'STRETCH', u'CHILD', u'2'], [u'PURPLE', u'SMALL', u'DIP', u'ADULT', u'2'], [u'PURPLE', u'SMALL', u'DIP', u'CHILD', u'1'], [u'PURPLE', u'SMALL', u'DIP', u'CHILD', u'1'], [u'PURPLE', u'LARGE', u'STRETCH', u'ADULT', u'2'], [u'PURPLE', u'LARGE', u'STRETCH', u'CHILD', u'2'], [u'PURPLE', u'LARGE', u'DIP', u'ADULT', u'2'], [u'PURPLE', u'LARGE', u'DIP', u'CHILD', u'1'], [u'PURPLE', u'LARGE', u'DIP', u'CHILD', u'1']]
```

---

If you do want to write this yourself, the problem with your code is that your first loop reads *all* of the lines from the file. You either have to rewind the file handle back to the beginning with `f.seek(0)` after the loop ends, or parse it in one go by implementing a simple state machine:

```
attributes = {}
data = []

reading_data = False

with open('balloons-adult-stretch.arff', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        line = line.strip()

        # Ignore comments and whitespace
        if line.startswith('%%') or not line:
            continue

        # If we have already reached the @data section, we just read indefinitely
        # If @data doesn't come last, this will not work
        if reading_data:
            data.append(line)
            continue

        # Otherwise, try parsing the file
        if line.startswith('@attribute'):
            key, value = line.split(' ', 2)[1:]
            attributes[key] = value
        elif line.startswith('@data'):
            reading_data = True
        else:
            #raise ValueError('Cannot parse line {!r}'.format(line))
            pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea and the solution. I will give sometime to the arff package.

Comment: @BlenderI was getting the error message at `attributes[key] = value`, then I changed it to `attributes.append(key)` as I needed the attribute name instead of the attribute values. Is it correct way ?

Comment: @Abrar: If it works, it works. You could also just use `attributes.keys()` and leave it as a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, in the for loop, you have already reached the EOF (end of file). That means that, once you start the lambda function, there is nothing left to read in the file. You could find a way to read the data in within that for loop, or if you want to do it (somewhat) inefficiently, you can do this:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
attributes = []
with open('stuff.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f.readlines():                                     ##1
       items = l.split(' ')                                    ##2
       if items[0] == '@attribute':                            ##3
            attributes.append(items[1])
    f.seek(0)                         ##4
    data = dropwhile(lambda _line: "@data" not in _line, f)     ##5
    next(data,"")                                               ##6
    for line in data:                                           ##7
        print(line.strip())                                 ##8
print(attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

line 5 to 9 is not part of the for loop anymore, so "f" is not defined i guess

Comment: I can not use it inside the loop and when I removed the indentation, I got the error message that f in not define. So, I guess that is not an issue. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Sorry, i mean the for loop and "l" actually ;-) so not remove but add one indent...  but @Blender had a much better answer ;-)